# glibc's '-lmcheck' option and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, glibc

We've been trying to hunt down some heap corruption issues in our multi-threaded C++ apps. As one technique, we tried add -lmcheck to the libraries line of the application. This is causing the app to crash out with apparent heap corruption in relatively short order.

Our app does use both malloc/free and new/delete (as appropriate).

One of our team wondered if -lmcheck was in fact thread safe, and put a mutex around all malloc/free calls. The crashes went away.

Does anyone know if -lmcheck is supposed to support multi-threading? I wonder if we just mis-understand the tool we're trying to use and thereby causing ourselves unneeded worry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, mcheck is not thread-safe and should not be used with multi-threaded applications.  Doing so can introduce additional problems since there is no synchronization between the threads.  Here is the response from Ulrich Drepper (glibc maintainer) on the subject a few months ago:

> mcheck does not work for multi-threaded code. It cannot
>   possibly do. There is no way to fix
>   this with the technology underlying
>   mcheck.

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean that the questioner's "fix", although it appears to have prevented the crashes, is not actually valid, and that mcheck can't help him with his application?

Comment: I don't know enough about the current implementation of mcheck or the changes that were made in the code being tested to answer that question but I would probably stay away from it and find other tools to use instead.

Answer (score 2):

I should have checked that before we spent time fooling with it. Ahh well.

Here's the link to where that quote comes from (I believe):

http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6547

glibc documentation defect:

http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12751

has been opened to help avoid others from hitting this.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I can highly recommend valgrind - it will work with multithreaded applications - although it emulates threads, it doesn't actually itself use threads.